# Selenium Webdriver - Issue with clicking an element inside a table

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a page that contains a table with multiple rows/columns.  In one of the column, I have a link that says 'OK'.  I need to click on that link.

Here is my code but it works very inconsistently.  It clicks the 'OK' on few rows but fails to click the same on few other rows. Am I missing something here?

**Update:**
I got it working by using `colElement.findElement(By.linkText("OK")).click()` instead of `colElement.click()`

```cs
List<String> tableValues = new ArrayList<String>();
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.className("table"));
List<WebElement> rowCollection=element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@className='table']/tbody/tr"));
for(WebElement rowElement:rowCollection)
    {
    List<WebElement> colCollection=rowElement.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement colElement:colCollection)
        {
        if(colElement.getText().equals("OK"))
            {
            colElement.click();   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the `i_<something>` variables? You're already iterating over your list of `elements`? Other than that the code looks fine, what happens if you debug-and-step-through?

Comment: I can remove those.  The control seems to flow fine but the 'click' is not happening.  Also, if I do a sysout of colElement.getText() just before the colElement.click() line, I see 'OK' printed in the console.

Comment: Just so I understand, what should happen when the `OK` is clicked on?

Comment: A modal window gets opened.

Comment: Then that is your problem.  WebDriver freezes up when dealing with modal windows.  You will need to deal with it before continuing on in your code.  (If you don't know how, there are plenty of tutorials on SO)

Comment: I understand that any testing on the modal window requires special coding, like getting the window handles and switching the focus (including waits).  But my problem is even before moving into the modal window.  In the current stage, all I am trying to do is to make the WebDriver identify and click the 'OK' link. Are you saying that the WebDriver freezes even at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Is the element with the 'OK' in it a td or an anchor? If there is an anchor present in the table cell it may be more reliable to click on that instead of the parent td.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
if(colElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
```

instead  of

```
if(colElement.getText().equals("OK"))
```

Comment: Same result.  I was able to see it in the same proper case when I do the sysout.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of tests where I use code very similar to yours and it works fine. From my experience with these issues, I would add two things:

1) Change this line of code:

`if(colElement.getText().equals("OK"))`

to

`if(colElement.getText().trim().equals("OK"))`

2) Wrap the click into a `Wait` (letting the click to retry for a while).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This too did not work in my case, but strangely I got it working through colElement.findElement(By.linkText("OK")).click().

Comment: Great! In the end it is not so strange: the text **is** actually a _link text_ indeed :)